# Error when using combineReducers "Error: Reducer "assetsReducer" returned undefined during initialization."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

> Error: Reducer "assetsReducer" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null instead of undefined.

In my ReactJS app I have 2 reducers/actions (`assets` and `board`).

In my store.ts file I use `combineReducers` like so:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

import { IinitialState } from './shared/types'
// import reducer from './reducers/assets/'
import assetsReducer from './reducers/assets'
import boardReducer from './reducers/board'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  assetsReducer,
  boardReducer
});

export const defaultInitialState = {
  assets: [],
  portfolio: [],
  loading: false,
  overlay: false
};

console.log('rootReducer', rootReducer);

export function initializeStore(initialState: IinitialState = defaultInitialState) {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
  )
}
```

This should be correct, yet I get the following typescript error, and the console error above when I refresh my app on localhost.

> ```
> Type 'IinitialState' has no properties in common with type
> ```
>
> 'DeepPartial<{ assetsReducer: 
>   { assets: any; loading: boolean; portfolio: never[]; overlay: boolean; }; boardReducer: { overlay: any; assets: never[]; portfolio: never[]; loading: boolean; }; }>'.ts(2559)

[image]

---

**assetsReducer:**

```
import { Actions } from '../actions/assets'
import { defaultInitialState } from '../store'

export default (state = defaultInitialState, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.GET_ALL_ASSETS: {
      const { assets } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        assets,
        loading: false
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**boardReducer**

```
import { Actions } from '../actions/board'
import { defaultInitialState } from '../store'

export default (state = defaultInitialState, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.SET_OVERLAY_STATE: {
      const { overlay } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        overlay
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: What does `assetsReducer` look like?

Comment: @markerikson just added both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial state is incorrect. You initial state should look something like this:

```
export const defaultInitialState = {
  assetsReducer: {assets: [], loading: false, portfolio: [], overlay: false},
  boardReducer: {assets: [], loading: false, portfolio: [], overlay: false},
}
```

More information on this can be found in the [Redux Docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state)

Comment: Ah thanks that just fixed my typescript error, also had to update the interfaces... I'm close, just realized I needed to spread my reducers but now getting `"Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers."`

Comment: That is a seperate issue which I believe is related to @markerikson's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help again, btw mind a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775648/running-into-typescript-state-type-mismatch-error-inside-of-redux-store-file

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the other reply, it looks like you have a circular reference issue.

`store.ts` imports `assetsReducer.ts`, but `assetsReducer` tries to import `store` to get its initial default state value.

Therefore, when `assetsReducer.ts` loads, `store.ts` hasn't finished evaluating, and `defaultInitialState` is undefined.

You should reorganize things so that you don't have circular references any more.  The simplest approach is to have `assetsReducer.ts` define its own initial state value (and export it separately if it needs to be referenced elsewhere).

Comment: Thanks! Yes that was also bad design. So I fixed my bug with a combination of yours and @MattC's answers to +1. But to get my app to work again I need to spread my reducers. Posting my answer soon, but will check MattCs. Will ask him to update his too.

Comment: I still get `Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.` after the refactor, but will post a new question for that. But my app works again... Actually no I was wrong, spreading it caused the error... having a type match bug instead.

Comment: Mind a look at this one when you have a moment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775648/running-into-typescript-state-type-mismatch-error-inside-of-redux-store-file

Comment: Sorry, I'm a TS noob and can't help there.